# Improperly closed question?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, closed-questions

What is off-topic about [How can a process intercept stdout and stderr of another process on Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249703/how-can-a-process-intercept-stdout-and-stderr-of-another-process-on-linux/)

Comment: seems to have been reopened now [How can a process intercept stdout and stderr of another process on Linux?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/249703)